# Accessing a RichTextBox inside a TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I create a new tab with this:

```
private void addTabs(RichTextBox richTextBox,string name)
    {
        //Add Tabs
        try
        {
            if (tabControl1.TabPages.Count <= 8)
            {
                TabPage tabPage = new TabPage();
                tabPage.Controls.Add(richTextBox);
                if (name == null)
                {
                    tabPage.Text = "Page: " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
                    tabPage.Tag = "Page: " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    tabPage.Text = name;
                    tabPage.Tag = name;
                }
                richTextBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

                tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("You have reached the max threshold for tabs.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

This create a new tab and gives it a richtextbox.
I know how to save a file using the dialog but how do I access the richtextbox?

Comment: You mention saving a file.  What are you writing to the file?  The contents of the `RichTextBox`?  And where is that code?  Presumably it doesn't have access to the `richTextBox` variable?  Could you post some code for how you're trying to access the RichTextBox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're supplying the richtTextBox through a parameter. You can access it from where you called this function.

Or call your TabPage through the TabControl:

```
// The first control would be your richtextbox if that's the only control in
// the tabpage.
var richTextBox = (RichtTextBox)tabControl1.TabPages[index].Controls[0];
```

Comment: Ah thank you that worked. If I could upvote I would.